# Диалоговое окно для выбора файла потока ввода

Tags: c++, fstream

Написал простой векторный редактор и сохранение изображения идет в текстовый документ. Как сделать чтобы при нажатии на соответствующую кнопку открывалось диалоговое окно которое позволяло бы выбрать файл для открытия (точнее чтобы этот файл был потоком ввода ifstream)

Comment: Уточните, что Вы использовали для разработки GUI-части приложения.

Comment: graphics.h и windows.h

Comment: Используйте [`IFileOpenDialog`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb775834(v=vs.85).aspx).